# QXmlStreamReader reading <element><value/></element>

Tags: c++, xml, qt

I have some XML that an application generated that I am trying to parse. In this example, I am trying to parse the value "value" from the `</element>` tags, but it seems like QXmlStreamReader is expecting something to be read after `<value/>`, but "`<value/>`" is exactly what I am after.

Is the source XML incorrect or is there a way to get this value from QXmlStreamReader?

```
QString str = "<element><value/></element>";

QXmlStreamReader xml(str);
while (!xml.atEnd()) {
    xml.readNext();
    qDebug() << xml.name() << xml.readElementText();
}

if (xml.hasError()) {
    // Prints "Expected character data. 17"
    qDebug() << xml.errorString() << xml.characterOffset();
}
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Your XML is well formed. As you are using QXmlStreamReader, I assume you are using Qt 4.8. If you look through [the accepted answer to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4201175/why-cant-i-parse-a-xml-file-using-qxmlstreamreader-from-qt), it seems that the XML parser behaves somewhat weird?

Comment: There is no value for the <value> element in your xml. What do you want to parse then? Besides, you have to read values if the current element is a start element. So, add `if (xml.isStartElement()) ...` to your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading MrEricSir's answer regarding using xml.text() and noticing it returned a blank string, I did some more digging. I realized, xml.name() immediatly after xml.readNext() while inside "element" returned what I was looking for as well as a blank string ('value' for StartElement and '' for EndElement). That with vahancho's comment regarding `if (xml.isStartElement())` being missing, helped me narrow it down to return only 'value'. See here:

```
QString str = "<element><value/></element>";

QXmlStreamReader xml(str);
while (!xml.atEnd()) {
    xml.readNext();
    if (xml.name() == "element") {
        xml.readNext();
        if (xml.isStartElement())
           qDebug() << xml.name();
    }
}

if (xml.hasError()) {
    qDebug() << xml.errorString() << xml.characterOffset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can repro this using Qt 5.5, but I think the problem here is you're using [QXmlStreamReader::readElementText()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText) when there isn't any text to read. This function's documentation is [not very clear currently](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qxmlstreamreader.html#readElementText) for the case where the element is both a start and an end element:

> Convenience function to be called in case a StartElement was read.
>   Reads until the corresponding EndElement and returns all text
>   in-between. In case of no error, the current token (see tokenType())
>   after having called this function is EndElement.
>
> The function concatenates text() when it reads either Characters or
>   EntityReference tokens, but skips ProcessingInstruction and Comment.
>   If the current token is not StartElement, an empty string is returned.
>
> The behaviour defines what happens in case anything else is read
>   before reaching EndElement. The function can include the text from
>   child elements (useful for example for HTML), ignore child elements,
>   or raise an UnexpectedElementError and return what was read so far
>   (default).
>
> This function was introduced in Qt 4.6.

So what do you do? I'd suggest simply using `QXmlStreamReader::text()`, which works fine in your sample code.

Comment: QXmlStreamReader::text() returned a blank string for me. But QXmlStreamReader::name() while inside "element" returned 'value'. See my answer.

Comment: @ComputerEngineer88 There is clearly no text for the `value` element. Why would you expect it to return any?

Comment: Yes, based on the intention of _your_ code. We're not mind readers here.